# Two different forms of Bayes Rule give different results with estimated variables

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I’m developing a tool to calculate the probability of conclusions using facts and Bayes Rule. I’ve encountered quite a puzzle. The problem is that when I use two different forms of Bayes Rule and estimated variables I get two different results. Let me try to explain.

**Form A** - The **standard form** of Bayes Rule is:

P(conclusion | fact) = P(conclusion) x P(fact | conclusion) / P(fact).

**Form B** - P(fact) must be based on prior data. If P(fact) is not available, then the **no prior data form** of Bayes Rule can be used. This is:

P(conclusion | fact) = P(conclusion) x P(fact | conclusion) / 
(P(conclusion) x P(fact | conclusion) + (1 – P(conclusion)) x P(fact | not conclusion))

Let’s use an example. The **fact** (the effect) is that a graph shows a clear national GDP growth long-term trend after a recession was quickly corrected. The **conclusion** (the cause) is the long-term GDP growth trend is due to good management of economic policy. This gives us **five variables of interest**. All but the first are estimated.

1. P(conclusion | fact) = unknown. This is what we want to calculate.
2. P(conclusion) = .01. We start with a low prior probability so that we can accumulate evidence that P(conclusion | fact) is highly likely to be true.
3. P(fact) = .95. All data points to a clear strong trend. No data is contested.
4. P(fact | conclusion) = .99. The probability rises from .95 to .99 given the conclusion.
5. P(fact | not conclusion) = .05. If the conclusion is false, then the fact is thrown into high doubt. It somehow cannot be true at all. .05 represents extremely unlikely.

Plugging these five variables into the two forms of Bayes Rule, we get

- **Form A**: .01 x .99 / .95 = .01
- **Form B**: .01 x .99 / (.01 x .99 + ((1 - .01) x .05)) = .167

The two results, .01 and .167, do not agree. They are not even close. Why is this?

The discrepancy can be eliminated two ways, by changing estimates to calculated values using the other variables.

The first way to eliminate the discrepancy is to change **P(fact | not conclusion)** from .05 to .95. *But that makes no sense.* .95 says the fact is still highly true. But it cannot be highly true if the conclusion is false. A false conclusion would say “the long-term GDP growth trend is NOT due to good management of economic policy.” Therefore, it must be due to something else. What would that be? BAD economic policy? Luck? Sudden stimulus due to war? None of the alternative reasons make any sense, because in this case (the reaction by the US administration to the 2008 Great Recession) they did not occur, though that could be controversial. What I’m trying to explain is that estimates for P(fact | not conclusion) for this example will tend to be low.

The second way to eliminate the discrepancy is to change **P(fact)** from .95 to .06. *But that also makes no sense.* It says the fact is almost completely false. But the data trend is clear and uncontested. There’s no way it can be false.

Of interest is that when the two forms of Bayes Rule are used on problems where the variables can be set by counting in a sample space, there is no discrepancy. This makes me suspect that Bayes Rule works well for **sampling logic**, but does poorly for some types of **general logic**, where some variables must be estimated.

Form A’s result make little sense. The prior and the posterior probabilities are the same. That’s like ignoring an extremely useful fact. Reducing the estimate for P(fact) to increase the posterior doesn’t make sense, because that implies the less true the fact, the more true the conclusion.

Form B’s result makes the most sense. It agrees with intuition. Is this because when using general logic to estimate variables, general logic works best with form B and not form A?

Thanks.

Comment: You think a certain fact is almost surely true, yet unless a highly unlikely conclusion also happens to be true, the fact is very unlikely. That is a contradiction. At least one of your probability estimates is based on faulty reasoning.

Comment: Thanks. David. Can you explain your comment? The way I see it, the fact that a graph of GDP data shows a recession was quickly corrected and the trend continued for a long time has a HIGH probability of truth. Also, why is the conclusion highly unlikely? It is routine for administrations to take corrective action when recessions occur.

Comment: I did not say the conclusion was unlikely. You said that. Possibly you are completely misusing Bayes; I really cannot follow your logic.

Comment: Thanks. What part of my logic is hard to follow? I can try to explain it better.

Comment: "We start with a low prior probability so that we can accumulate evidence that P(conclusion | fact) is highly likely to be true." Why? The usual application of Bayes is that we choose the prior based on our best prior estimate. We don't deliberately choose a low prior just to show improvement.

Comment: Also, if the "conclusion" is false, why should that throw doubt on the "fact"? As you say, the "fact" is evident from the historical graph. If the "conclusion" is false then you might look for some other cause that would explain the "fact."

Comment: Why start with a low prior? If you don't have any facts about the conclusion, then subjectively you have no idea what the conclusion's probability is. Then you are forced to pick a low (.01), neutral (.5), or high (.99) prior. Beginning with a low prior means I want a lot of evidence before making a decision. See this paper: http://www.nyulawreview.org/sites/default/files/pdf/NYULawReview-88-5-Fields.pdf Page 16 in the PDF says "In the calculations below, I use a prior probability of guilt of 0.5, which can be conceptualized as equal likelihood of innocence or guilt." That's a neutral prior.

Comment: As you say, you could choose a low, neutral, or high prior. Without giving any good reason, you say the prior should be low; but everything else you say prior to the calculation (specifically, that the "fact" is very likely true, but that it would be very unlikely true if the "conclusion" were false) implies that the prior probability of the conclusion must be high.

Comment: Re: If the "conclusion" is false then you might look for some other cause that would explain the "fact." - Yes, good idea. In fact (pun intended) the online tool I'm building now has 21 arguments entered. All the conclusions have 2 or more inputs, such as facts. But the question I'm addressing in this post is why, given plausible estimates that make intuitive sense, do we get such different results from the two forms of Bayes Rule?

Comment: You do not have plausible estimates that make intuitive sense. The estimates are mutually contradictory.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain? Sorry these comments are limited to only 600 characters.

Comment: You already have an answer below. The formula in that answer is a law of probability. If your numbers do not make that formula true, then at least one of your numbers is wrong--and your numbers do not make that formula true.

Comment: Re: As you say, you could choose a low, neutral, or high prior. Without giving any good reason, you say the prior should be low; - I don't understand. I gave a reason: "Beginning with a low prior means I want a lot of evidence before making a decision." Then I provided a paper to demonstrate that selecting an arbitrary prior (such as low, neutral, or high) is accepted practice, if no evidence is available.

Comment: Re: You already have an answer below. The formula in that answer is a law of probability. If your numbers do not make that formula true, then at least one of your numbers is wrong--and your numbers do not make that formula true. - Thanks. I know that, but I don't know logically WHY the two formulas get different answers, given plausible estimates for the variables.

Comment: **YOU DO NOT HAVE PLAUSIBLE ESTIMATES.** Sorry for shouting, but I think you have no idea what is "plausible" or not in a situation like this. Suppose someone told you, "I just drew a right triangle, and I plausibly estimate that the legs have lengths $6$ and $8$ and the hypotenuse has length $15.$" Would you think that is plausible? Or would you say, "Your numbers violate the Pythagorean Theorem, therefore at least one must be incorrect."

Comment: Thanks David. The post lists the five variables of interest. Number 1 is the result. The rest are the estimates. A short description of each is given explaining why I think each estimate is plausible. I appreciate the insight that "you do not have plausible estimates." But for that to be helpful, could you explain why some of the estimates are implausible?

Comment: I cannot tell you which number is implausible, only that _taken together_ they are not plausible. How about that right triangle with sides $6,$ $8,$ and $15$? Can you tell me which of those numbers is implausible?

Answer (score 2):

P(FACT) =(P(conclusion) x P(fact | conclusion) + (1 – P(conclusion)) x P(fact | not conclusion)) by law of totaly probability
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability so it is not 0.95

Comment: Thanks papasmurfete. Yes, I know that. It gives P(fact) = .06. That's how form B of Bayes Rule calculated the answer without having to know P(fact). My question is why, given plausible estimates that make intuitive sense, do we get such different results from the two forms of Bayes Rule. Form A uses variables 2, 3, and 4. Form B uses variables 2, 4, and 5. P(fact) is variable 3.

Comment: _Both_ forms of Bayes' rule have P(fact) in the denominator. The only difference is that in the "no prior data" form, P(fact) has been expressed in other terms using the law of total probability.

Comment: Furthermore think that:
From Form A variables 2,3,4: youve got that P(fact | not conclusion))= [P(fact)-P(fact|conclusion)xP(conclusion) ]/P(not conclusion)=[0.95-0.01x0.99]/0.99=0.949. But from Form B: you get P(fact | not conclusion))= 0.05, so one of your way of gaining your info for your variables is fault or probably false interpreted.